# Is there an other place than the changelogs to see if a debian package is corrected or not?

Tags: linux, cve

I would like to know if there was an other place to see if a debian package is fixing a CVE than the changelog of the packet. For instance the packet `bind9 1:9.7.2.dfsg.P3-1` is fixing the `CVE-2010-3613` [here](http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/main/b/bind9/bind9_9.7.3.dfsg-1~squeeze11_changelog), can we see it somewhere else? To be more specific, can we see it in a place where we can compute the reading ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian provides a feed for its security advisories: http://www.debian.org/security/dsa. There is a link to each advisory which lists the CVE addressed by that fix. The `debian-security-announce@debian.org` [mailing list](http://www.debian.org/MailingLists/) provides the same information. These advisories have been declared [CVE-compatible](http://www.debian.org/security/CVE-certificate.jpg). The email and RSS feeds are the most timely way to retrieve advisories. See the [section on security advisories](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-howto/ch7#s-dsa) in the manual for more context.

Additionally, Debian publishes an [advisory cross-reference](http://www.debian.org/security/crossreferences) which lists all the advisories with the CVE that they address (as well as Bugtraq IDs, CERT advisories and US-CERT vulnerability notes). MITRE also publishes a [CVE reference map](http://cve.mitre.org/data/refs/refmap/source-DEBIAN.html) listing CVEs addressed by each DSA.

I don't know of any “official” place where you can retrieve the CVE-to-package-version map in a single go. From the Debian cross-reference, you need to follow the DSA links to know what package version brought the fix.